# Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined using Jquery 3.1 as static resource in salesforce lightening

Tags: lightning, jquery

I am facing an error while using Jquery 3.1 library in lightening. 
I am facing this error only when I click on setup or dev console in other words only when I click a button which opens in a new tab.
I am facing the same issue while deleting a component which created dynamically.

Error:
[Cannot read property 'nodeType' of undefined]
Object.handlers()@https://anvi-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/1555616133000/abaav_pm__jquery31:5119:29
Object.dispatch()@https://anvi-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/1555616133000/abaav_pm__jquery31:5068:40
Object.elemData.handle()@https://anvi-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/resource/1555616133000/abaav_pm__jquery31:4895:28

[image]

Comment: Hi Suhesh, welcome to SFSE. I think this question and your solution are likely to be interesting to other users, but right now, there's not enough information or a code sample to allow others to benefit from it. Could you flesh out both parts of your post?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fixed it by adding some if conditions in the Jquery library to handle nulls
Below images have code and classes where I have added if condition to handle undefined data in events
[image]

[image]